# How to send custom mail when a user complete a specific form

Tags: plugins, customization, forms, email, contact

I've been looking for the whole day for a plugin that help me to solve my problem with my website.

Is there a way to create a specific form that could send a custom e-mail when the user complete it?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your question... What exactly are you looking for? Because Contact Form 7 does exactly, what you've described. But I don't believe that you haven't found it after whole day of searching... ;)

Comment: I've tried Contact form 7 but I can't connect a specific mail template to a specific form.
What i'm trying to do is to make a form for a page that send a specific mail for new registration from that form.
Is there any "hidden" option i'm not seeing?
Thanks for any further explaination

Comment: so you definitely haven’t researched it enough...

Comment: Time to watch some hindi tutorial i guess :)
Oh, and thanks for the hint!

Comment: no need plugin if you create custom its good for you. you can create easily. so below answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many plugins for that :- 
1) Contact form 7
2) Ninja form
If you want to insert a post or product you can choose gravity form.

Answer (score 0):

it help you to create custom functions.
if you want to create/send mail custom then you should try wp_mail ( which is wordpress function  )  or php core function is mail(). do proper R & D on it and its parameter also.

parameter also provide you sender info and receiver info.

on submit your form you can use these functions.

reference links for mail functions :-

wordpress :- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

php       :- https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

i hope its help you.
thank.